# Max return value if empty query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have this query:

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers
    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8)
    .Max(x => x.ShoeSize);
```

What will be in `maxShoeSize` if company 8 has no workers at all?

**UPDATE:**
How can I change the query in order to get 0 and not an exception?

Comment: Naor
: have you heard of LINQPad?

Comment: I don't understand why you would ask 'What will be in `maxShoeSize`?' if you had already tried it out.

Comment: @jwg: I guess I wanted to see if you know the answer :)
Eventually I got a better way to do what I asked and this is what I meant.

Comment: @Naor, this isnt a guessing game. I also would downvote the original question. If you know the answer give it to us otherwise you look lazy. Just now I was about to do the same question and I prepare all info including the exception message.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8)
                         .Select(x => x.ShoeSize)
                         .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                         .Max();
```

The zero in `DefaultIfEmpty` is not necessary.

Comment: Works :) But on my code the zero in DefaultIfEmpty was necessary.

Comment: Regarding the first part of the question, which is not fully answered here: 
According to [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__), if the generic type of the _empty_ sequence is a reference type, you get null. Otherwise, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414674/linq-max-extension-method-gives-an-error-on-empty-collections/), calling `Max()` on an empty sequence results in an error.

Comment: This **won't work for EF Core 3.1 and later** if the type is not nullable. Reason being there is a left join for all entries which will fail for non nullable types. Use `Workers.Where(...).Max(x => (int?)x) ?? 0;`. This generates efficient max query directly in sql.

Comment: If this a query to the database with EF, will this not bring all the lines to calculate in memory the max value?

Comment: @DanielLobo It certainly appears to have done so for me... While Alby's solution generates a simple `Select Max(col) from table WHERE ...`

Answer (score 86):

I know this is an old question and the accepted answer works, but this question answered my question about whether such an empty set would result in an exception or a `default(int)` result.

The accepted answer however, while it does work, isn't the ideal solution IMHO, which isn't given here. Thus I am providing it in my own answer for the benefit of anyone who is looking for it.

The OP's original code was:

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8).Max(x => x.ShoeSize);
```

This is how I would write it to prevent exceptions and provide a default result:

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8).Max(x => x.ShoeSize as int?) ?? 0;
```

This causes the return type of the `Max` function to be `int?`, which allows the `null` result and then the `??` replaces the `null` result with `0`.

---

**EDIT**
Just to clarify something from the comments, Entity Framework doesn't currently support the `as` keyword, so the way to write it when working with EF would be:

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8).Max<[TypeOfWorkers], int?>(x => x.ShoeSize) ?? 0;
```

Since the `[TypeOfWorkers]` could be a long class name and is tedious to write, I've added an extension method to help out.

```
public static int MaxOrDefault<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, int?>> selector, int nullValue = 0)
{
    return source.Max(selector) ?? nullValue;
}
```

This only handles `int`, but the same could be done for `long`, `double`, or any other value type you need. Using this extension method is very simple, you just pass in your selector function and optionally include a value to be used for null, which defaults to 0. So the above could be rewritten like so:

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8).MaxOrDefault(x => x.ShoeSize);
```

Hopefully that helps people out even more.

Comment: Great solution! The more popular `DefaultIfEmpty` answer only works well when `Max` isn't doing an evaluation.

Comment: @McGuireV10 Yeah, I don't typically like using `Select` as a middle man when I'm just going to be using an aggregate function like `Max` on the result. I also _think_ (I haven't tested this yet) that the generated SQL would use an extra subselect query by doing that, while mine would just deal with an empty set by returning null. Thanks for the upvote and feedback! ;)

Comment: @McGuireV10 Similarly, if the `ShoeSize` was actually in a related `Uniform` entity, I would not use `Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8).Select(x => x.Uniform).Max(x => x.ShoeSize)`, instead I would just keep the entire evaluation in the `Max` function: `Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8).Max(x => x.Uniform.ShoeSize)`. I prefer to use as few methods as possible in my queries to allow EF to have the greatest freedom in deciding how to efficiently construct queries. ;-)

Comment: Looking back over my last comment, I see that I forgot to add the `as int?) ?? 0` portion from my answer. Additionally, in my preferred method, care would have to be taken that it's only used when querying the database and not local objects if `Uniform` could be null. Or if you're using C#6, you could just change it to `.Max(x => x.Uniform?.ShoeSize) ?? 0` and that would both handle a null `Uniform` and it would change the datatype to `int?`. C#6 is awesome! ;-)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in EntityFramework. Can anyone shed any light?  (Using the DefaultIfEmpty technique worked).

Comment: @MoeSisko What do you mean you couldn't get it to work? What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: In EF: 
int max = context.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName == "blah").Max(s => s.StudentID as int?) ?? 0;
gives error:  "The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'System.Int32' and a check of type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries."

whereas: 
int max = context.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName == "blah").Select(s => s.StudentID).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
returns 0.  May be an EF issue.

Comment: Interesting. I actually happened to see a similar error just a few hours ago. Don't know if it's something new or what. But it's definitely specific to EF.

Comment: @cptRobby - It seems if you call "ToList()" after "Where", then it works in EF. e.g. this returns 0:  
int max = context.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName == "blah").ToList().Max(s => s.StudentID as int?) ?? 0;

Comment: That is to be expected, since the `Max` is no longer being run on the database through EF. But that does mean that EF is returning all of the records from the database that match the where clause, which might be fine if you only expect a few records to match the where clause.
But I think it would be more efficient to use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` because `ToList` will actually create a `List` in memory and iterate through the records to populate it, while `AsEnumerable` just causes the database query to run and provides the results.

Comment: A generic version of the extension method:`public static TResult MaxOrDefault<TElement, TResult>(this IQueryable<TElement> items, Expression<Func<TElement, TResult>> selector, TResult defaultValue = default)
    where TResult : struct
    => items.Select(selector).Max(item => (TResult?)item) ?? defaultValue;`

Comment: Async version: `public static async Task<int> MaxOrDefaultAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, int?>> selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await source.MaxAsync(selector, cancellationToken) ?? 0;`

Comment: @Th3B0Y Yup, async has become far more significant to how I use EF (and most other things) since I first wrote this answer, so it's nice to include that. ;-)

Answer (score 38):

[Max()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343284.aspx) won't return anything in that case.

It will raise [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) since the source contains no elements.

Comment: It will only raise `InvalidOperationException` if the objects in the list are a non-nullable type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You are talking about the worin `Max` method. The question is about a query so the discussed method is [`Queryable.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.max?view=netcore-3.1). It may be similar but for example the documentation does not state that it throws an `InvalidOperationException `

Answer (score 19):

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8)
                     .Select(x => x.ShoeSize)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty()
                     .Max();
```

Answer (score 14):

If this is Linq to SQL, I don't like to use `Any()` because it results in multiple queries to SQL server.

If `ShoeSize` is not a nullable field, then using just the `.Max(..) ?? 0` will not work but the following will:

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x = >x.CompanyId == 8).Max(x => (int?)x.ShoeSize) ?? 0;
```

It absolutely does not change the emitted SQL, but it does return 0 if the sequence is empty because it changes the `Max()` to return an `int?` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

```
int maxShoeSize=Workers.Where(x=>x.CompanyId==8)
    .Max(x=>(int?)x.ShoeSize).GetValueOrDefault();
```

(assuming that `ShoeSize` is of type `int`)

If `Workers` is a `DbSet` or `ObjectSet` from Entity Framework your initial query would throw an `InvalidOperationException`, but not complaining about an empty sequence but complaining that the materialized value NULL can't be converted into an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Max will throw System.InvalidOperationException "Sequence contains no elements"

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();

        list.Add(new MyClass() { Value = 2 });

        IEnumerable<MyClass> iterator = list.Where(x => x.Value == 3); // empty iterator.

        int max = iterator.Max(x => x.Value); // throws System.InvalidOperationException
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public int Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

NB: the query with `DefaultIfEmpty()` may be significantly **slower**. 
In my case that was a simple query with `.DefaultIfEmpty(DateTime.Now.Date)`.

I was too lazy to profile it but obviously EF tried to obtain all the rows and then take the `Max()` value.

Conclusion: sometimes handling `InvalidOperationException` might be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary within `.Max()` to handle the predicate and set its value;

```
// assumes Workers != null && Workers.Count() > 0
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Max(x => (x.CompanyId == 8) ? x.ShoeSize : 0);
```

You would need to handle the `Workers` collection being null/empty if that's a possibility, but it would depend on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x=>x.CompanyId == 8).Max(x => x.ShoeSize) ?? 0;
```

Comment: I think this will fail as Max is expecting an int and it is getting a null; so an error has already occurred before the null-coalescing operator comes into effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there are any workers before doing the Max().

```
private int FindMaxShoeSize(IList<MyClass> workers) {
   var workersInCompany = workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8);
   if(!workersInCompany.Any()) { return 0; }
   return workersInCompany.Max(x => x.ShoeSize);
}
```