# LINQ Max extension method gives an error on empty collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
var maxNumber = dbContext.Where(a => a.Id == 9).Max(a => a.Sample_Num);
```

If there is no Id of 9, I get an error. I like to default the result to 0 if there is no Id of 9.

I tried:

```
var maxNumber = dbContext.Where(a => a.Id == 9).Max(a => a.Sample_Num) ?? 0;
```

as well as other variations but was not able to get it to work

Comment: I can't see any GroupBy in the above code... :)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You could use `Any` to check if there's a matching element:

```
int maxNumber = 0;
var id9 = dbContext.Where(a => a.Id == 9);
if(id9.Any())
{
    maxNumber = id9.Max(a => a.Sample_Num);
}
```

or you could use [`DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx):

```
int maxNumber = dbContext
    .Where(a => a.Id == 9)
    .Select(a => a.Sample_Num)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Max();
```

Comment: Agreed. I hate to use `Any()` because it forces enumeration a second time.

Comment: The Select + DefaultIfEmpty + Max is the way to go when you want a MaxOrDefault.

Comment: Note that for `IQueryable<T>` and some providers (*cough* NHibernate), `DefaultIfEmpty` is not implemented.  I wrote my own MaxOrDefault: `query.OrderByDescending(expression).Select(expression).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Sorting to find the maximum is not very efficient. It might not be too noticeable with smaller datasets, but the larger it gets, the more time you're spending putting all the other values you don't care about in order.

Comment: @KenLyon your comment was referring to the previous comment or my answer?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was referring to the previous comment by @ThomasSTrias where he used `.OrderByDescending`. Sorry for the confusion. I'm still not very familiar with the best way to tag people in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Paul Is it so bad? I thought `Any()` iterates a maximum of one element before returning.

Comment: @LucasMorgan: He meant that you need to enumerate the sequence twice if you first want to check if there are Any(first enumeration) and then you start consuming it. In my code above the part in the `if`: `id9.Max(a => a.Sample_Num)`. That's the second enumeration of the sequence `id9` which might be an expensive query. My second example avoids that by using a single query.

Comment: @LucasMorgan I really just meant in general. It will iterate one only sure. But consider how expensive that can be. If you have an `OrderBy` above the `Any` it must evaluate everything in order to get to the `Any`. Consider Link to SQL. `Any` will perform `select top 1` from the database. Unless I have a pre-enumerated set like an `Array` or `List` I shy away from using `Any`.

Answer (score 9):

Just use the nullable version of Max (even though the values aggregated are not nullable):

`var maxNumber = dbContext.Where(a => a.Id == 9).Max(a => (int?)a.Sample_Num) ?? 0;`

It is almost what Nate tried.
The point is that Max of nullables gives null from an empty collection as a result, while Max of ints gives an exception as its return value is an existing int of the collection.
You force it to be Max<int?> by explicitly declaring result as of that type.
Then you can specify the desired default value after ??.

Answer (score 2):

You may try simple implementation of MaxOrDefault without need to convert anything. Just check the selector parameter inside Max function:

```
var maxNumber = dbContext.Where(a => a.Id == 9).Max(a => a?.Sample_Num) ?? 0;
```