# How to handle null value in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting maximum code from database but how should I handle it when there is no record? It returns error as null reference no record

```
int maxCode = context.Persons.Max(p => p.pCode);
```

EDIT:

This answer is to check first time the null value when you deployed app other wise the suggested answer only match condition with id but i no want to match condition i only have to check weather **there are records in table or not**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max return value if empty query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966680/max-return-value-if-empty-query)

Comment: Use `DefaultIfEmpty` - there are plenty of duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no rows, maxCode is set to zero.

```
int maxCode = context.Persons.Any() ? context.Persons.Max(p => p.pCode) : 0;
```

Comment: `context.Entry(p).GetDatabaseValues();`   but why this is not allowing me to insert in database for first time when database have no value

Comment: GetDatabaseValues cannot be used for entities in the Added state.