# C# Entity Framework select max after where filter of not nullable field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, max, where-clause, nullable

I have a not nullable field (`Num`)

```
class MyTable
{
    //...
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

want to find maximum `Num` for `Category == "A"`

```
var maxnum = myTable
   .Where(r => r.Category == "A")
   .Max(r => r.Num);
```

the problem occurred when there wasn't any record of `category == "A"` . Because the result of `Where()` is null so the result of `Max()` will be null but when `Num` is not nullable the exception occurred.

I can fix it by setting `Num` as nullable in table design but I don't like this solution while `Num` should has value and shouldn't be nullable.

Any suggestion? Is there a way that I accept null value for Num while Num is not nullable? or any better query?

Comment: so if the `Where.(r => r.Category.Equals("A")` part of the query is null, and `Num` isn't nullable, I would expect it to give you an exception since there is no record of `Num` where `Category.Equals("A")`? so look into `DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: See [DefaultIfEmpty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int maxShoeSize = Workers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 8)
                     .Select(x => x.ShoeSize)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                     .Max();
```

See : [Max return value if empty query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966680/max-return-value-if-empty-query)

Comment: OK duplicate question! while I couldn't find that question in search, anyway I add some tags to that question maybe helps better search result later.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way that I accept null value for Num while Num is not nullable?

Sure you can:

```
//...
.Max(r => (int?)r.Num);
```

Every non nullable value can be turned into nullable (but not vice versa). I personally prefer this method (which acually is suggested in the exception message) because it allows me to distinguish between no max value and max value of 0 (zero) or even `int.MinValue`.

Comment: UP for answering to the additional ask. I think DefaultIfEmpty is better solution for such questions but as you advised it is better if we don't like to get 0 for empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var maxnum = myTable
   .Where(r => r.Category == "A")
   .Max(r => r.Num) ?? 0;
```

Then you can work with the 0 result.