# C# Entity Framework Select ENTITY Where(a.Value = me.Value) AND a.Version is MAXIMUM

Tags: c#, select, entity-framework-6, max, where-clause

I am Using Entity Framework 6 and I am trying to select the Entity with the maximum version number where Id = myId.

So consider.

```
Public class MyObject
{
  int Id {get;set;}
  int Version {get;set;}
  string stuff {get;set;}
}
```

I have looked at this answer
[C# Entity Framework select max after where filter of not nullable field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217741/c-sharp-entity-framework-select-max-after-where-filter-of-not-nullable-field/37217837)

But it only gives me the Integer value as the result - I want the Entity itself the whole record, the Whole Enchilada if you will..

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
var obj = myDbContext.MyObject
.Where(x => x.Id = myId)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit: sorry, I had overlooked your extra requirement, i.e. the where clause..