# What is the query for getting legder Id for both new or existing customer in Ledger Table?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

This is only work for existing Customer in Ledger Table:

```
var i = (from u in dc.GetTable<Ledger>()
         where u.C_Id == u.Customer.Id &&
         u.Customer.Name == textBox1.Text
         select u.Id).Max();
```

This is only work for new Customer in Ledger Table:

```
var i = (from u in dc.GetTable<Ledger>()
         where u.C_Id == u.Customer.Id &&
         u.Customer.Name == textBox1.Text
         select u.Id).SingleOrDefault();
```

`System.InvalidOperationException` occurred in `System.Data.Linq.dll`

Provide me the solution for both new and existing customer in Ledger Table. what is the query for getting Ledger Id for both case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max return value if empty query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966680/max-return-value-if-empty-query)

Comment: Does changing `SingleOrDefault` to `FirstOrDefault` help?

Comment: yes but isn't working `FirstOrDefault()` for both cases.

Comment: `SIngleOrDefault()` works well for new customer in ledger and `Max()` works well for existing customer in ledger table.

Comment: In searches such as this, based on user input, when you never know, will it return data or not, you never use `SingleOrDefault` or `Max`. Always use `FirstOrDefault`. Even that doesn't make sense since you [probably] want to display all results that returned by query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want the highest ID if their are multiples but this should work

```
var ledger = 
     dc.GetTable<Ledger>()
     .Where(l => l.C_Id == l.Customer.Id)
     .Where(l => l.Customer.Name == textBox1.Text)
     .Select(l => l.Id)
     .OrderByDescending(id => id)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i want the highest id because there many ids for one customer thats why!

Comment: How is it not working? An error? Wrong results? In which case?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I got the right query**! This is the query for getting ledger Id for both new or existing customer in Ledger Table

```
var i = (from w in dc.GetTable<Customer>() //customer id
         where w.Name == textBox1.Text
         select w.Id).SingleOrDefault();

int? j = dc.Ledgers.Where(x => x.C_Id == i)
                   .Max(x => (int?)x.Id);
```

Comment: Thats two queries and the first should throw an exception if you get more than one matching name. You said there are many ids for the customer, have you tested it with data where the first part returns multiple records?

Comment: I give you (F-) for this solution