# Lambda query to return Max() of Date or else null in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I need Lambda query to filter dates from list and return Max Date. If the list does not satisfy the filter then should return a null value. This is my code, need a shorter version ->

```
var a = Dates.Where(x => x >= DateTime.Now).Select(x => x);
if(a.Count > 0)
{
  return a.Max();
}
else return null;
```

The value returned to is in DateTime? format which shows error "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement".

Comment: Use a ternary operator

Comment: Why do you need a shorter version? You probably do need a version that compiles, though. `a` doesn't have a `Count` property. It has a `Count()` method -- which as Eric is about to suggest, isn't a very good approach anyhow. You just want to know if it's got *any* items in it.

Comment: I have a jar that can contain any number of pennies. My question to you is: are there any pennies in the jar?  Now, think about it: **do you have to count the pennies in order to answer the question**?

Comment: Why is there a trivial select on the end of the query? That makes no sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max return value if empty query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966680/max-return-value-if-empty-query)

Comment: can you show the method signature and it's return type where the code sits in.. update / edit your question to show it.. also is your return type declared a `Nullable` you would need to return `(Nullable<DateTime>)null` or `default(DateTime?)` need more information / code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Dates = new List<DateTime>();

DateTime? max = Dates.Where(x => x >= DateTime.Now)
    .Select(x => (DateTime?) x)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    .Max();

Console.WriteLine(max == null ? "null" : "not null");
```

You need to cast the result to `Nullable<DateTime>` one way or another, if your list is composed of `DateTime`.

Edit : as @RogerStewart mentioned in comments, to perform the cast you could use `Cast<DateTime?>()` instead of the Select statement.

Comment: Depending on preference, could use `Cast<DateTime?>()` instead of the `Select()`.