# ToListAsync() fails on ASP NET CORE but ToList() works - Error "Sequence contains no elements."

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I get a list like:

```
var test = await list.ToListAsync();
```

this function works fine with ASP.NET MVC but with the migration to .NET CORE I have the error

> Sequence contains no elements.

The list object is an `IOrderedQueryable`.

When I execute the sentence:

```
var test = list.ToList();
```

works correctly but I need a Async method...

EntityFrameworkCore Version: 2.1.1

Any idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it will get you the required list.

Your interface signature would be like this

```
Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsyn();
```

Your implementation would be like this.

```
public virtual async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsyn()
{
   return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I get the list with a select that fails because a MAX() inside the select fails.

Max() issue (Only happends with EntityFrameworkCore ): -> [Stackoverflow: Max return value if empty query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966680/max-return-value-if-empty-query)

Answer (score -1):

check the imports
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`
if found an import has the name of EntityFrameworkCore but does not begin with Microsoft, deleted.

Comment: See the answer by Carlos himself: the issue had nothing to do with EF, packages, or even ToList(Async). It was a bug in the query and the error was thrown correctly.